# How to verify passwords with nodejs?

Tags: python, node.js, flask

I am moving my python flask app to nodejs. Previously I was hashing the password with `werkzeug.security.generate_password_hash(password)`. How do I verify the password hash in nodejs? Here is the code:

```
async function verify(password, hash) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const [salt, key] = hash.split(":")
        crypto.scrypt(password, salt, hash.length, (err, derivedKey) => {
            if (err) reject(err);
            resolve(key == derivedKey.toString('hex'))
        });
    })
}
```

Whenever I try out the code, it returns `false`. Could someone explain to me the solution?

Comment: Per https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/utils/?highlight=security#werkzeug.security.generate_password_hash that method defaults to pbkdf2, **not** scrypt.

Answer (score -1):

you should get the user data first to get the hashed password and hashkey and then encrypt the passed password with the saved key then check is it equal to the hashed one.

```
  // passing the incoming password from the user and the user data 
  // user = {password: '<the hased passowrd>', hashKey: '<the salt hash key for this user>'}
  async function verify(password, user) {
    const requestedPassword = await this.encryptPassword(password, user.hashKey);
    return requestedPassword === user.password;
  }

  async function encryptPassword(password, hashKey) {
    return await bcrypt.hash(password, hashKey);
  }
```

Comment: Is this method compatible with werkzeug?